# UPDATE and INSERT in two different table with a field with the same name/value

Tags: mysql, sql

How to do UPDATE and INSERT in two different table with a field with the same name/value with one line only?

Comment: You cannot do that, because Data Manipulation Language (part of SQL) does not allow modifications to more than one table to be done in a single DML statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do so for inserts or standard SQL, but in MySQL, you can update two tables at once using a `JOIN`;

```
UPDATE table_a a
JOIN table_b b 
  ON a.id=b.id
SET a.value = a.value+1, b.value = b.value-1
WHERE a.id=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43858/1).

Answer (score 1):

You just can't do that.

You can maybe use a trigger on the `INSERT`'s statement table to `UPDATE` the second table or the other way around.

Other than that you have to use two different statements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible since UPDATE and INSERT are two different (or at least separate) operations...